# Group By clause changes the results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like

```
SELECT weeks_ind, weeks_rol, weeks_no, date,
CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN rec = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END "rec",
CASE  WHEN (SUM( CASE WHEN glob is null THEN 1 WHEN glob = Id THEN 2 ELSE 0 END ))  = 3 THEN 'Many'      
WHEN (SUM( CASE WHEN glob is null THEN 1 WHEN glob = Id THEN 2 ELSE 0 END ))  = 2  THEN 'One'       
ELSE 'None' END "Type"
FROM Table WHERE Id = '12345'
AND ((visible = 'Y' AND rec = 'N') OR rec = 'Y') AND days = 100
GROUP BY date, weeks_no, weeks_ind, weeks_rol
ORDER BY date, weeks_no;
```

And works well, as expected, returns all records.
But if i add to GROUP BY the "rec" as

```
GROUP BY date, weeks_no, weeks_ind, weeks_rol, rec
```

The query does not return all the records and more than that, the Type is wrong.
Any ideas why is this happening? I know the group only groups the records and does not influence the number of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rec` in the `GROUP BY` is the one in the table, not the one in your query that's been reduced to just 'Y'/'N'.

You would need to put in an inner query, something like:

```
SELECT weeks_ind, weeks_rol, weeks_no, date,
CASE  WHEN (SUM( CASE WHEN glob is null THEN 1 WHEN glob = Id THEN 2 ELSE 0 END ))  = 3 THEN 'Many'      
WHEN (SUM( CASE WHEN glob is null THEN 1 WHEN glob = Id THEN 2 ELSE 0 END ))  = 2  THEN 'One'       
ELSE 'None' END "Type"
from (
  SELECT weeks_ind, weeks_rol, weeks_no, date,
  CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN rec = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END "rec"
  FROM Table WHERE Id = '12345'
  AND ((visible = 'Y' AND rec = 'N') OR rec = 'Y') AND days = 100
  GROUP BY date, weeks_no, weeks_ind, weeks_rol
) group by date, weeks_no, weeks_ind, weeks_rol, rec
ORDER BY date, weeks_no;
```